# javascript get json from another site

Tags: javascript, json

I need to get data from another site. The site returns json.
I tried this:

```
function get_data() {
    $.getJSON("https://kde.link/test/get_field_size.php",
        function(data){
            var get_width = data.width;
            var get_height = data.height;
            /* some code here */
    });
};
```

But this doesn't work. Moreover, I've got this mistake: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://kde.link/test/get_field_size.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
How can I get data from another site?

Comment: This is the cross-origin policy in play. Do you have access to `kde.link`? Try adding support for JSONP if you do.

Comment: To access to third party site you will need to use server side proxy. like `proxy.php?url=https://kde.link/test/get_field_size.php`

Answer (score 1):

Due to the [`same origin policy restriction`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) that's built into the browsers you cannot make cross domain AJAX requests. If you need to do that you will need to have access to the server side script (`get_field_size.php`) and either enable [`CORS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or [`JSONP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

With CORS, the server must support the `OPTIONS` HTTP verb and send a special `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in which it explicitly lists the domains that can call it.

If you don't have control over this remote script then you will have to write a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge between the local and the remote domain. Then you will make the AJAX request to your local script:

```
$.getJSON("/get_field_size_bridge.php",
    function(data){
        var get_width = data.width;
        var get_height = data.height;
        /* some code here */
});
```

The bridge will then act as a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm complete noobie in JS. So I don't think that I'll be able to write a server side script. Isn't there another way to do that?

Comment: No, not without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens when we request something from another site of our own.
Please just add this on the top of your php file to handle the request.

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

hope helps, good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try this updated code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>JQUERY AJAX POST JSON CAPTURE NAME:VALUE Pair</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" /></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $.ajax({
            url: 'https://kde.link/test/get_field_size.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { },
            success: function(response) {
              alert(response.width);
              alert(response.height);
            }
          });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, that didn't work. Got that same error.

Comment: Answers shouldn't be walls of code with no explanation. What exactly have you changed and why should it make a difference?

Comment: And having "paste it in your favorite text editor" … it throws exactly the same exception that was quoted in the question.

Comment: Tried but without any success. Thanks for your try.

Comment: I added an external source of jquery,, It should work on your end cause it is completely working on mine